# Make iPhone vibrate: AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate) undeclared

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio, vibration

I want to make iPhone vibrate and I found the code

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

but Xcode 4.3.2 reports error: undeclared identifier kSystemSoundID_Vibrate

What's the problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try:

```
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

**EDIT**: Also make sure you import `AudioToolbox.framework`

- `#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`

Comment: Same error and there's no AudioServicesPlayAlertSound() method. Is it right to add AudioToolBox.framework?

Comment: Hi, can we make the iPhone Vibrate 2 times with the above one ?  @skram

Comment: how do you set the duration of the vibration using this method?